# how to convert json without &quot

Tags: javascript, json

```
var text = [{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en3&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:234},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en4&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:135},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en1&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:335},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en2&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:310},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en5&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:1548}]
```

how to convert to json without "?

like:`[{"name":"en3","value":234},`and so on?

i have try to use `JSON.parse('${resultData}'.replace(/&quot;/g, '\\"'))`,but it throws error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token \`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace your regEx with `/&quot;/g, '"'`

i.e the code should be `JSON.parse('${resultData}'.replace(/&quot;/g, '"'))`

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en3&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:234},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en4&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:135},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en1&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:335},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en2&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:310},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;en5&quot;,&quot;value&quot;:1548}]"
```

remove `&quot;` from above string as

```
var text=text.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
```

then parse text array as

```
var json=JSON.parse(text);
```

then check the vlaues as....

```
  for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)
        { 
            console.log(json[i].name);
            console.log(json[i].value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `\\`:

```
'${resultData}'.replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
```

Better yet: don't encode the `"` as `&quot;` in the first place.